# Correctly setting the delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I seem to be having some difficulty setting my delegate in my app.  I think this is partially due the it being a UIPageView.

In my DetailPage (the UIPageViewController)

```
#import "PhotoViewController.h"

@interface DetailPageController : UIPageViewController <UIPageViewControllerDelegate, PhotoViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) PhotoViewController *photoViewController;


@end
```

And in the .m

```
#import "DetailPageController.h"
#import "DetailPageModelController.h"

@interface DetailPageController ()

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.modelController.photos = self.photos;


    UIViewController *initialController = (UIViewController *)[self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:self.initialIndex storyboard:self.storyboard];
    self.delegate = self;

    [self setViewControllers:@[initialController]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO
                  completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                  }];

}

- (void)photoCall
{
    NSLog(@"called from photoCall");
}

@end
```

I am setting the page view based off a modal, I can set the view controller and it displays fine.  But I don't know where to set my delegate?  I never allocate the view controller (PhotoViewController) anywhere.

ModalController.m:

```
#import "DetailPageModelController.h"
#import "PhotoViewController.h"
#import "Media.h"

@implementation DetailPageModelController

- (UIImage *)photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    if ([self.photos count] == 0 || index >=[self.photos count]) {
        return  nil;
    }

    Media *object = [[Media alloc] init];
    object = self.photos[index];
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [object.asset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];

    return image;

}

#pragma mark - convenience methods

- (PhotoViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard
{

    UIImage *photo = [self photoAtIndex:index];

    if (photo == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    //No segue, load manually
    PhotoViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoViewController"];
    controller.photo = photo;
    controller.num = index;

    return controller;

}

- (NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(PhotoViewController *)controller
{
    //Returns the position in array of photos that current picture is
    //Same as current view controller
    return controller.num;
}

#pragma mark - page view data source
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(PhotoViewController *) viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(PhotoViewController *) viewController];
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.photos count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}
```

Then the actual page view has code as following:

PhotoViewController.h

```
@protocol PhotoViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)photoCall;

@end


@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController


@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *photo;

//storyboard
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<PhotoViewControllerDelegate> photoViewControllerDelegate;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "PhotoViewController.h"

@interface PhotoViewController ()

@end

@implementation PhotoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self setPhotoView];
}

- (void)setPhotoView
{

    [self.imageView setImage: _photo];
    self.imageView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

}

- (void)callingHome
{
    NSLog(@"tcd called");
    [_photoViewControllerDelegate photoCall];
}

@end
```

The method callingHome is called on a button press, i'm just trying to find where to set this delegate.

The way I see it is it should work like this:

Button Pressed -> callingHome is called
callingHome is called -> _photoViewControllerDelegate calls the method photoCall in my main UIPageView Controller

It logs to console and we are done!

Comment: So much context is missing here. When is your photos V.C. instantiated? When would your page view controller have a reference to it?

Comment: Ah Carl, hello again.  The VC is instantiated in the modals controller.  If you look at the main PageView controller, it takes the modal controller, gets the index of current page and then at same index out of an array of photos and displays that exact photo in the photo view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
UIViewController *initialController = (UIViewController *)[self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:self.initialIndex storyboard:self.storyboard];
self.delegate = self;
```

With

```
PhotoViewController *initialController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:self.initialIndex storyboard:self.storyboard];
initialController.delegate = self;
```

And in the rest of your application, whenever you instantiate a `PhotoViewController` to be managed by a `DetailPageController` instance, make sure to set the page controller as the delegate of the photo view controller. For example, change your `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` methods as shown:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(PhotoViewController *) viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    PhotoViewController *photoVC = [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
    if ([pageViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PhotoViewControllerDelegate)]) {
        photoVC.delegate = (id<PhotoViewControllerDelegate>)pageViewController;
    }
    return photoVC;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(PhotoViewController *) viewController];
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.photos count]) {
        return nil;
    }

    PhotoViewController *photoVC = [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
    if ([pageViewController conformsToProtocol:@protocol(PhotoViewControllerDelegate)]) {
        photoVC.delegate = (id<PhotoViewControllerDelegate>)pageViewController;
    }
    return photoVC;
}
```

Or modify your `viewControllerAtIndex:storyboard:` method to take a delegate parameter and do the assignment there. However is convenient for you - just make sure you assign those delegates whenever you're creating them to go into your pages.

Comment: YES, you sir are very helpful.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: On second thought, that works for the page currently in view, but I just realized it doesn't apply when I swipe to the next page or any other.

Comment: I believe that it is setting the initial controller but then that controller disappears when I swipe away.

Comment: Do you implement `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` anywhere? Can you not set the delegate to be the calling instance there?

Comment: Why Yes I do, inside my modal controller, which makes the previous and next controller.  But I wouldn't be setting the delegate there right? As then that would mess things up.  (I updated my code by the way.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly and you have been very helpful with helping me learn.

Comment: For some reason I had thought that by putting it there it would not affect the current page, but I was wrong and it all works.  Thanks!